# svelte-navigator: TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'indexOf')

Tags: typeerror, svelte, indexof

I'm new in svelte. I try to make client side routing with svelte-navigator lib but I'm getting an error when I try to build it.

```
npm run dev

09:24:58 [vite-plugin-svelte] ssr compile in progress ...
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'indexOf')
```

src/routes/+layout.svelte

```
<script>
    import Header from './Header.svelte';
    import './styles.css';

    import { Router, Route, Link } from "svelte-navigator";
</script>

<Router>
    <div class="app">
        <Header />

        <main>
            <Route path="/">
                <h3>Home</h3>
                <p>Home sweet home...</p>
            </Route>
        
            <Route path="about">
                <h3>About</h3>
                <p>That's what it's all about!</p>
            </Route>
        </main>
    </div>
</Router>
```

svelte.config.js

```
import adapter from "@sveltejs/adapter-static";

export default {
  kit: {
    adapter: adapter({
      // default options are shown. On some platforms
      // these options are set automatically — see below
      pages: "build",
      assets: "build",
      fallback: null,
      precompress: false,
      strict: true,
    }),
  },
};
```

I've tried to find solution in google and ask my friends programmists but with no effect.

Comment: There's a difference between Svelte https://svelte.dev/ and SvelteKit https://kit.svelte.dev/  With SvelteKit you don't need an additional router. If you want to use `svelte-navigator` instead, create a plain Svelte project via `npm init vite` and select the svelte option

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Can I make lazy loading in sveltekit?

Comment: You probably can and if you already searched and are stuck with a concrete attempt, it's best to start a new question. For general questions there's alternatively also the Svelte discord or reddit channel

Answer (score 0):

and vite.config.ts

```
import { sveltekit } from "@sveltejs/kit/vite";
import { defineConfig } from "vite";

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [sveltekit()],
  optimizeDeps: { exclude: ["svelte-navigator"] },
});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).